# Unable to create album in android Facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting responce:

```
11-27 13:10:27.299: E/CreateAlbum(6725): SURU CREATE ALBUM RESPONSE: 9 {Response:  
responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 2, errorType: 
OAuthException, errorMessage: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request 
later.}, isFromCache:false}
```

below is what i am doing

```
public void createNewAlbumRequest(Activity activity, Session session, String albumName) {
if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
  Log.e("CreateAlbum", "SURU CREATE ALBUM RESPONSE: 2 Session Null");
  return;
}
  Bundle params = new Bundle();
  params.putString("name", albumName);
  Log.e("CreateAlbum", "SURU CREATE ALBUM RESPONSE: 5");
  Callback callback = new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
      Log.e("CreateAlbum", "SURU CREATE ALBUM RESPONSE: 9 " + response.toString());
    }
  };
  Request request = new Request(session, "me/albums",
      params, HttpMethod.POST,
      callback);
 request.executeAsync();
}
```

For session i am doing:

```
private final List<String> PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS = Arrays
        .asList("publish_stream", "manage_pages", "publish_actions");

LoginButton login_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
login_button.setPublishPermissions(PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
login_button.performClick();
```

I don't understand where i am doing wrong can any one help me.

Comment: You need publish_actions and user_photos permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need publish_actions and user_photos permissions